# Delaying ASP.Net async postback until my code completes - trouble with placeholder polyfill in webforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, postback

Because of a third-party product we're building upon, I'm forced to work in ASP.Net webforms for a web application I'm working on. The project owners are very insistent on using placeholder text in the textboxes, even though our primary userbase is running IE9, which doesn't support placeholder text in textboxes. For this reason, I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin to add this behavior. Right now I'm using [Simple-Placeholder](https://github.com/marcgg/Simple-Placeholder).

This would work great on an MVC style site, which does normal submits, as it binds to the form's submit function, and clears out all the placeholder text before submitting. This prevents the placeholder text from being sent back to the server.

In our WebForms project, we're using lots of UpdatePanels to prevent the entire page from refreshing all the time. This presents a problem for placeholders. These async postbacks are sending back the placeholder text to the server... so the "Name" field sends back a value of "Enter name here" for example.

So... when an async postback happens, I need to clear all the placeholder text from my textboxes before letting the postback continue.

I'm getting close to a solution. I'm adding a "beginRequest" handler that clears the placeholder text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        // add function to handle simple placeholders before async postbacks
        Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

        function appl_init() {
            var pgReqMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            pgReqMgr.add_beginRequest(
                $.proxy($.simplePlaceholder.preventPlaceholderSubmit, $(document))
            );
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, this happens asynchronously, so the postback continues on before I'm done updating the controls on the page. As a result, the placeholder text gets sent on to the server anyway.

What I really want to do is wait for my function to return before continuing on with the postback.

I have another potential solution. I'm modifying the __dopostback function to run my code first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        __doPostBack_old = __doPostBack;
        __doPostBack = function (args) {
            if ($.proxy($.simplePlaceholder.preventPlaceholderSubmit, $(document))()) {
                __doPostBack_old(args);
            }
        };
    });

</script>
```

While this works, it smells bad... I'm concerned that there may be some other mechanism that might kick off an async postback that doesn't call __dopostback.

Hope that all made sense. Any thoughts, ideas, or insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By the time beginRequest fires PageRequestManager has already grabbed the textbox values for the AJAX request. That is why changing the textboxes in beginRequest event doesn't work.

Have you tried calling your preventPlaceholderSubmit in the initializeRequest event instead? I believe this event fires before PageRequestManager builds the request. The only problem is that the user can cancel the async postback, clearing the placeholder text without submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I tried using initializeRequest, but it turned out not to work. I did however, find a different placeholder plugin that creates the placeholder text by floating a label in front of the textbox, thus leaving the textbox value untouched. ( https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim ) This is much more webforms-friendly and I don't have to worry about doing work before the postback.